# Store a variable by reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

```
let myDivContent = document.querySelector(".myDiv").innerHTML;
myDivContent += "Hello";
```

`myDivContent` appears to be a variable that contains the content of the div. Is it possible for it to hold a reference to the innerHTML of the div in order for the code above to work as intended?

Comment: It’s not possible to do that.
You would have to do

document.querySelector(".myDiv").innerHTML +=  “Hello”

Comment: just do `myDivContent.innerHTML += "Hello";` instead or even better  `myDivContent.textContent += "Hello";` and remove the `.innerHTML` from the previous line

Comment: Perhaps worth stating that, in JavaScript, strings are immutable objects, so having a _reference_ to a string doesn't give you the ability to modify it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic of a "reference" can only be accomplished by a shared variable, property name or by a closure.

A closure is the only thing that can really do a *reference* the way you are imagining it.  You'd need two functions.  One for getting and one for setting:

- `get: () => thing`
- `set: value => thing = value`

This creates a "reference" to `thing` in the way that you are thinking.

The other issue is that `+=` requires us to get and set the same value, so we'll need to use a *property* to achieve that.  But properties need an object, you can't just have a bare property.  So let me describe a few approaches:

#### Approach 1 - no closure

Here's one way you could use a property to create an object that *refers* indirectly to some other object (without a closure).  Properties allow you to use the `+=` syntax to modify an arbitrary value such as a string the way you demonstrated.

I'll define the reference to be an *object* and a *property* of that object.

```js
class Ref {
  constructor(obj, prop) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.prop = prop;
  }
  get value() {
    return this.obj[this.prop];
  }
  set value(val) {
    return this.obj[this.prop] = val;
  }
}

const person = { greeting: "Hello" };
const ref = new Ref(person, 'greeting');
ref.value += ' world';
console.log(person);
```

In the example above I've created an object `{ greeting: "Hello" }` and stored it in a variable called person.  Then I create a `Ref` that refers to that object and the `greeting` property name.  You can say `ref.value += 'something'` because reading from `ref.value` calls the *getter* and writing to `ref.value` calls the *setter*.  The `+=` operator does both -- it reads and then writes, thus modifying the object.

This has limited flexibility and requires that you have an object and a property to refer to the thing that you want to be able to get/set.

#### Approach 2 - closure

The above `Ref` example is not flexible enough to refer to a local variable.  For example, it doesn't have a way to modify the `person` variable, but it can modify the object that the `person` variable refers to.  So, in general, if you need more flexibility, you could install properties on the fly and refer to the thing to be modified using a *closure* in the getter & setter with an arrow function like this:

```js
var myLocalVariable = "Hello";
Object.defineProperty(this, "ref", {
  get: () => myLocalVariable,
  set: val => myLocalVariable = val
});
this.ref += ' world';
console.log(myLocalVariable);
```

You can't have a bare property, though, so you'll have to assign the getter/setter to an object.  You can use `this` like I did above, but in cases where that is inappropriate, you'll have to create your own object to hold the property.

#### Approach 3 - just keep it simple

In your case, you may want to just keep a reference to the element `myDiv` rather than to its content `myDivContent`.  This is flexible enough to refer to any *object* (but not to a variable).  That may be good enough for most cases.

```js
let myDiv = document.querySelector(".myDiv");
myDiv.innerHTML += " world";
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector(".myDiv").innerHTML` doesnot holds a reference to the html content, instead it returns the a string that contains HTML serialization of the element's descendants.

So you cannot use like `myDivContent += "Hello";`.

The better apprach is to hold your selector in a variable and update its value as

```
let myDiv = document.querySelector(".myDiv");
myDiv.innerHTML += "Hello";
```

Here the variable `myDiv` holds a reference to the selector, hence you can update the `innerHTML` like above